# CSS not displayed on GitHub Pages?

Tags: css, git, github

I need help regarding a mini project I'm working on. It's a simple site and it does not do any much yet. But when I push it on Git, CSS seemed to be not working.

Link: https://chxrain.github.io/Mini-School/

I tried changing the href link to the ff and it still doesn't work:

./css/style.css
../css/style.css
./Mini-School/css/style.css
../Mini-School/css/style.css
/css/style.css
/Mini-School/css/style.css
\css\style.css

Big thanks to those who can help!

Comment: Did you try to just use `css/style.css`?

Comment: yes, it's currently on css/style.css

Comment: Your website works fine, just press Ctrl+F5 to hard refresh.

Comment: Yes, your website worked really fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the true link of the logo

[image]

Comment: and for all img too

Comment: yes thank you. I'll fix them all. I got too focus on changing the CSS href link when in fact, linking the images on all pages should be fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

For internal linking of files, the proper way of calling it will be:
/RepositoryName/folder/image.jpg

In my case, it is /Mini-School/media/image.jpg (which is inside the media folder)

CSS link remains as css/style.css (which is inside the css folder)

Answer (score -1):

make sure that your local modification or your css is pushed into git

Comment: Yes, it's the first commit after modifying all files

Comment: can you send the complete link of the page

Comment: This(answer) should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @ANDOAndriamalala, yes it's https://chxrain.github.io/Mini-School/

Comment: the true link for the logo is
../Mini-School/media/logo.png

Comment: @ANDOAndriamalala, I tried without the two dots and is not working. Thank you!

Comment: I'm still about to review your code, I'll send it to you later

Comment: @ANDOAndriamalala, it's working fine now. Sorry there was a typo from NOT to NOW. It also works without the 2 dots. Thanks again

Comment: for me it's work by removing / before media in all html pages